# Couchbase view not updating after set from PHP SDK

Tags: php, couchbase, couchbase-view

I am working on an application, where I work mainly with views for getting the data.
What I try to do is, to store a document, redirect and check if the stored document is available(this is done via view, because I am not looking for the document key but for a different value).

**What am I using?**

PHP(5.4.21), Couchbase(2.1.1) and the PHP SDK for Couchbase(1.1) on a Debian Wheezy.

**So what's happening?**

I store a document with the API function `set($id, $document)`, then trigger an update of the view with the API function `view($designDocument, $viewName, $options)`, where the `$options` contain at least `'stale'=>false`, and then redirect to another page where I check for the newly added document/or simply want to display it.
But the newly added document is not always shown or not always passes my check for existence.

Following the code I am using in more detail:

```
public function store(AbstractDocument $document)
{
    $result = $this->bucket->storeDocument($document->getId(), 
                                           json_encode($document));
    $this->afterSave();

    return $result;
}

public function storeDocument($id, $document)
{
    if (!is_string($document)) {
        $document = json_encode($document);
    }
    $res = $this->couchbase->set($id, $document);

    return $res;
}

public function afterSave()
{
    $this->bucket->triggerViewIndexing(
        $this->getDesignDocumentName(),
        Config::KEY_COUCHBASE_VIEW_USER_USERLIST
    );
}

public function triggerViewIndexing($designDocument, $viewName)
{
    $options = ['limit' => 1, 'stale' => false];
    $res     = $this->couchbase->view($designDocument, $viewName, $options);
}
```

As shown in the code, I am setting the stale parameter to false, to ensure an updated index.
But it appears not to be working.

Before writing this question, I looked at quite some threads in the Couchbase forum, posts on Stackoverflow, the documentation of the PHP SDK for Couchbase and the general documentation of Couchbase.
So I think I understand how [stale](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#index-updates-and-the-stale-parameter) is supposed to work and what [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16594537/2686625) there seem to be.
If my assumption that stale works, but only when the document is no longer in the memory but is being written to disk(or already has been), is wrong, please feel free to correct me.

As what I am trying to do is not working, I tried different things, that also have been mentioned in several explanations and documentations to be supposed to help achieve my desired outcome.

For example, I thought if the default behaviour of `stale` is `update_after`, then triggering an update of the index twice, would solve the problem.
Well, it didn't.

The other notable things are

```
$this->couchbase->keyDurability($id,$res);
$this->couchbase->observe($id, $res);
```

I used those directly after storing the document with `set`, separately and out of desperation in combination.
Didn't do the trick either.

My assumption what is wrong here is, that the PHP SDK either is somehow not passing through the `stale=false` parameter and [keyDurability](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-php-client-1.1.5/classes/Couchbase.html#method_keyDurability) doesn't do what it is supposed to. As I pass `stale=false` in when checking for the newly created document as well, of course both(trigger and check) works on the same bucket and view.

Or I am doing something horribly wrong without noticing it.

I'd be glad if someone could point me in the right direction and hopefully explain what's going wrong, as I can't grasp what's happening. According to my understanding, everthing should work with `keyDurability` and `stale` at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" about updating views is, that it only uses data that is persisted to disk.
You can use keyDurability() to check if this has happened, BUT you need the id and the cas of the element you just wrote.

I would change your triggerViewIndexing function to look like this.

```
/**
 * @param $designDocument
 * @param $viewName
 * @param null $id
 * @param null $cas
 */
public function triggerViewIndexing($designDocument, $viewName, $id = null, $cas = null)
{
    if (!empty($id) && !empty($cas)) {
        $details = [
            'persist_to' => 1, //The number of nodes the document should be persisted to
            'timeout'    => 2000, // The max time to wait for durability
            'interval'   => 100 //The interval between checking the state of the document
        ];
        $this->couchbase->keyDurability($id, $cas, $details);
    }

    $options = ['limit' => 1, 'stale' => false];
    $res = $this->couchbase->view($designDocument, $viewName, $options);
}
```

This will check every 100ms for a maximum of 2000ms if the item is written to disk.
After that, triggering the view will refresh the data.

Comment: Funny, I did try passing along the id and cas as parameters, but I didn't pass along any additional parameters($details) as they all are supposed to have default values.
According to the php sdk documentation persist_to defaults to 1, so no need, I thought. But seems that does the trick.

For me, this looks like that could be another error(or call it bug if you want) in the php sdk, as I previously tried using the id and cas but the persist_to works.

Thanks mate, helped a great deal!